# JOIN SQL function results with multiple WHERE from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I only have a single table that has 4 columns: A,B,C and D

I have a table of the `SUM` of C for all A-B combinations.

```
SELECT 
A,
B,
SUM(C),
FROM Table
GROUP BY A, B
```

I have a table of the `AVG` of D for all A-B combinations when C = 1.

```
SELECT 
A,
B,
AVG(D),
FROM Table
WHERE C = 1
GROUP BY A, B
```

**What it the best way to regroup these `SELECT` statement in a single query keeping my `GROUP BY A, B`?**

I tried to `RIGHT JOIN ... ON A.Table = A.Table AND B.Table = B.Table`, but that did not exactly worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT A, B, SUM(C),
       avg(case when C = 1 then D end)
FROM Table
GROUP BY A, B
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT A, B,
    Sum(C) SumC,
    Sum(case C when 1 Then D else 0 end) /
    Sum(case C When 1 then 1 else 0 end)  AVGOfDForC1Rows,
FROM Table
GROUP BY A, B
```